# Groovy: how to escape a string for executing a shell command?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline that I read a yaml file from a repository and execute it with `sh`. If the string has commands like `echo ${ENV_VAR}`, the shell will substitute it. To prevent security problems, I would like to escape it.

I'd like something like [Apache commons-text `escapeXSI`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXSI-java.lang.String-) without the need to install anything.

There is [StringEscapeUtils](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/json/StringEscapeUtils.html), but it just has Java and Javascript special chars escape methods.

Comment: I think if you just pass the command to echo, that itself isn't a security problem. e.g. if the var="hello > test.file"; echo ${var} will not write to a file.

Comment: The problem is that I'm executing the command. I'd like to somewhat  limit what the user can do.